# Close tmux Session After Script Ends

Tags: ssh, tmux, python3, session

The remote Python script is executed by a local script using ssh so this is not an interactive session.

The tmux session is only useful while the script runs and want it to end after the script is finished.

Is there something similar to "**cmd /c**" or "**cmd /k**", where the window closes or stays open after execution ends?

Comment: Try running `/my/script.sh ; exit` in `tmux`. This will only quit `tmux` if you don't have other panes/windows open.

Comment: The moment "timux send python3 /my/script.py ENTER" is executed the most I can do is attach to the session to look at the output of the script (Python print()'s), any commands to "exit" or "send exit ENTER" are not executed. Same for "send C-l", sometimes it works, other times I see "^L" as console output. It depends on the timing of the execution and order of commands in the local one-line script. And because the remote Python script is run in the tmux session it probably can't end the tmux session.

Comment: Do not use `tmux send` to run a command in `tmux`. `tmux new-session`, `tmux new-window`, `tmux split-window` and few other `tmux` commands can take a shell command as a string. Similarly you can `tmux kill-pane` (possibly via a separate `ssh` connection) instead of trying to terminate a program by sending keys. With `tmux` command you communicate with the tmux server and you can tell it what to do in what pane/window/session. Forget about `tmux send`, unless sending a key is exactly what you want to do. If you want to run something then you want to *run something*, not send keys.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1492284/432690).

Comment: Only need one session and one window for the duration of the remote Python script, then the tmux session should end after the script is finished. This is executed non-interactively with a local script using ssh. How can I use the following general idea to do that? "tmux set-window-option -g remain-on-exit off; tmux new-window -dn python3 /home/pi/script.py"

Comment: Well, exiting is the default behavior. `ssh server 'tmux new-session -d "sleep 60"'` will start a session that ends in 60 seconds. Note `ssh` exits right away because `tmux` (the tmux client) exits because of `-d`, but tmux server stays and you can `ssh -t server 'tmux attach'`. Or you can run a command and stay attached in the first place: `ssh -t server 'tmux new-session "sleep 60"'`. This `ssh` will exit after 60 seconds, unless you detach manually first. If the session doesn't exit then this means `remain-on-exit` is enabled, maybe in the tmux config.

Comment: Yes, verified it is the default behavior, thanks. However, the only way I've been able to execute commands in the tmux session is by using "send-keys" with a detached session. Also, wanted to see the initial output of the Python script after attaching to the tmux session then have the ssh window close after 5 seconds, but the Python script blocks any other commands.